# Could not build Objective-C module 'mupdfdk'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, mupdf

I'm trying to add mupdf framework to a swift project. I created a new project and copied the mupdfdk.framework to my project and referenced it in the frameworks section. Following is a screenshot of the documentation.

[image]

Now my project looks like this.

[image]

Then when I try to import it in viewcontroller, I get `Could not build Objective-C module 'mupdfdk'` error. Are there any other steps I'm missing? Please help.

Comment: Perhaps something is wrong with the mupdfdk.framework you have - where did you get it from? Can you build the mupdfdk example app okay?

Comment: Yes, the example app builds and runs fine. I copied the mupdfdk.framework from the example app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this bridging header:

*MuPDF-Bridging-Header.h*

```
#ifndef MuPDF_Bridging_Header_h
#define MuPDF_Bridging_Header_h
#import "mupdfdk.framework/Headers/mupdfdk.h"
#endif /* MuPDF_Bridging_Header_h */
```

and declare it within the Swift Compiler section of the Build Settings:

[image]

Comment: Actually, that step should be unnecessary, and what the OP was doing should have worked without it. There's a fault in this version of mupdfdk.framework. If you edit the contained file mupdfdk.modulemap and correct "sodk.h" to "mupdfdk.h" that will fix the problem. Thank you to [JosephH] for pointing this out through other channels.